# Datagridview column sorting when clicking on the column header

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a `datagridview` with two columns `name` and `price`.

If I click on the column header, the corresponding column will be sorted in alphabetical order. Do I need to add any event handler for sorting the datagrid view column? Or is there any property to set for sorting datagrid view column? I am working on a Windows application using C#.

Would anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could use javascrip/jQuery I would suggest you to use the JQuery plugin [Datatabe](http://www.datatables.net/).

With that you can get the colum sorting, colum reordering, filtering and search all together.

EDIT:

If not javascript, then you can use the following guide: [DataGrid sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/0868ft3z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I am not doing web applications, i am doing windows applications sorry......  I am not sure whether javascript and jquery languages are used in windows applications(winforms)....

Comment: In window application you could use the WebBrowser control on one of your forms to be able to use jQuery. But the link I sent you should already be the solution for your question.

Comment: i am very sorry the above link you have given is not working in my code i have posted new one pls see this question..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152063/trying-to-sorting-the-data-grid-view-column-shows-error-message