# trying to sorting the data grid view column shows error message

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

I have a datagridview with columns

```
                           customername 
                           customerimage
                           price
```

when i click on the column header the entire datagridview will be sorted for that i have tried the code given in this link    http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/0868ft3z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

```
   private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {

         /// i have just put the code given in that link 

              if (newColumn == null)
              {
    MessageBox.Show("Select a single column and try again.",
        "Error: Invalid Selection", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

    }
```

but it will shows the above message when i click on the column header even if there are some columns has values ......

would any one pls help on this....

many thanks ......

Comment: you have to show us how and where you assign a value to newColumn !!

Comment: I am binding the datagridview by using entity framework ..... that is seperate from this ....  i ahve just changed the name of datagridview  given in that link.. do i need to do any other approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is when you are clicking the header it is not selected.
You must set the selection mode to column header select:

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.ColumnHeaderSelect;
```

This must be done before the call of dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(). You can put it in the constructor of the form or onLoad() for example.