# Datagridview Column Click/Sort

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, columnsorting

HI guys as you all know if someone clicks the column header it will sort. However is it possible to do something after they sort. Like if it sort ascending a msgbox would prompt out saying you sort ascending. I would like to know which datagridevent it is. If possible any tips of how to tell whether the column is sorted or not? i found this link but its actually Web Form i need to do it in windows form any ideas?

[Datagridview column sorting when clicking on the column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140800/datagridview-column-sorting-when-clicking-on-the-column-header)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  Private Sub dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) _
        Handles dataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick

        Dim newColumn As DataGridViewColumn = _
            dataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex)
        Dim oldColumn As DataGridViewColumn = dataGridView1.SortedColumn
        Dim direction As ListSortDirection

        ' If oldColumn is null, then the DataGridView is not currently sorted. 
        If oldColumn IsNot Nothing Then 

            ' Sort the same column again, reversing the SortOrder. 
            If oldColumn Is newColumn AndAlso dataGridView1.SortOrder = _
                SortOrder.Ascending Then
                direction = ListSortDirection.Descending
' Msgbox HERE
            Else 

                ' Sort a new column and remove the old SortGlyph.
                direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending
                oldColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.None
               ' Msgbox HERE
            End If 
        Else
            direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending
' Msgbox HERE
        End If 

        ' Sort the selected column.
        dataGridView1.Sort(newColumn, direction)
        If direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending Then
            newColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending
        Else
            newColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Descending
        End If 

    End Sub 

    Private Sub dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) _
        Handles dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete

        ' Put each of the columns into programmatic sort mode. 
        For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In dataGridView1.Columns
            column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic
        Next 
    End Sub
```

Source : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadermouseclick.aspx)

Comment: I need to be able to sort, but I create the DataGridView1 dynamically, so I can't place the code above anywhere, since the grid doesn't yet exist?

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me too much time and headache :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  If _Data_Table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        datagridview.DataSource = _Data_Table


        datagridview.Sort(grd_Cadastro.Columns("Your column name"), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)


        datagridview.AutoResizeColumns()
        datagridview.ClearSelection()



    Else
        datagridview.DataSource = Nothing
    End If
```